# set charset="utf-8" in content type

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc

I use a plugin for jquery to post data(using POST method) when redirecting to a page .

https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js

This plugin send data(param) with POST method when redirecting to inserted url .
but i have utf-8 character in my Object . when i try to get object in my server side (java)  ,  it's  wrong for example like this :   Ø´Ù?Ø¨Ù?

how i edit content type and add charset="utf-8"

Here is default content-type (without edit) : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

AND PLUGIN USAGE EXAMPLE :

```
     $.redirect("/reserveTicket.rose" , {name : "تهران"} , "POST");
```

Comment: Please declare utf-8 as charset right from the top of the document

Comment: Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: @Dennisrec Excuse me but I did not understand what you said .